# Measuring time in assembly

Tags: linux, assembly

For the several hours now, I was trying to find a way to measure time interval within assmebly code. What I have seen so far, is that I can query the number of CPU cycles, but of course, I'd need to know CPU frequency to translate number of cycles into time. I have found the rdmsr instruction, but it is ring0 instruction, and ring0 is not something I can to put my code in.

Some examples I've found call Windows Query* functions for this, but I am not running on Windows. Is there any way for me to measure time interval in user level? Any other way to get frequency, or may be other clock I can access directly? One-second resolution system clock is of course out of the question :)

Comment: On a single processor with one core or (presumably) for very short programs, `rdtsc` might do it.

Comment: @cad, how would rtdsc do it? It is still going to give me the number of cycles, not time!

Comment: Have you tried `gettimeofday`? It returns unix epoch (seconds) as well as microseconds.

Comment: @JoelC, there are two issues with that. First, it is time-consuming itself - takes half a microsecond on my machine. Second, microsecond is not precise enough.

Comment: How precise do you need this measurement to be?

Answer (score -2):

I spent quite a while working with cycle counters, and eventually came to the (perhaps obvious) conclusion that RDTSC counts cycles, not time. It will never count time because the computer's clock is being constantly ramped up and down by the power management unit. So the cycle counter is extremely precise for measuring cycles, horribly off by random amounts in real time units. I believe Intel eventually addressed this by locking the cycle counter to a clock that is not affected by the PMU, but I haven't investigated it.

The Windows Query* functions do not actually use the RDTSC cycle counter. I thought they did until I tried to measure *really* small periods and found it had a 14MHz(?) tick, which turned out to be the PCI data bus clock.

On top of all this, each core has its own cycle counter. So have to pay attention to which core you are using when executing the RDTSC opcode. And each core has its own PMU.

The best timer you will find in Windows user mode is QueryPerformanceCounter() and QueryPerformanceFrequency().

Comment: I have never seen such a random answer before. You start with telling me what I'have said in my question (it counts cycles, not times), than explain some features of the function I can not use because it is available in a different operating system from the one I am using, and end up sugesting using it. Along the way, you fail to educate yourself on the fact that modern CPUs do have constant and non-stop tsc.